# localScroll after updating div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

So I have a [localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) which smooth scrolls to an element when clicked.

`$("ul#nav").localScroll({duration:400, target: "#container", offset: -20});`

that I am trying to have still work when `ul#nav` has been updated with new `li` elements.

I know that I can use the `.on()` instead of `.click()` for elements that get updated within a div but I was wondering what I would do for `.localScroll()`

Comment: What is "localScroll"?

Comment: reinitialize plugin, i guess

Comment: @epascarello sorry, updated the question.

Comment: In link you posted: `Dynamic content( AJAX, AHAH, or simply jQuery )

The plugin supports dynamically added/loaded anchors and local links. You need to set the option 'lazy' to true. Note that the matched elements (#navigation in the first example) must be preserved in the DOM. But any content inside it can be modified. You don't have this problem if you use the global call.`

Comment: I should of read more carefully. Thank you @A.Wolff this worked perfectly.